# How does Play! 2.3.x verify cookies haven't been tampered with?

Tags: cookies, playframework, session-cookies, digital-signature, playframework-2.3

In the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash#How-it-is-different-in-Play) for Play 2.3.x:

> Of course, cookie values are signed with a secret key so the client can’t modify the cookie data (or it will be invalidated).

I was curious to see how Play validated signed the cookies. So following the code, cookies are [parsed from the header](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L137) and [decoded in the Cookie helper](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L712) but when I view the `request` `cookieheader` the data doesn't have a signature?

[At this line](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L755) the expression `cookieHeader` evaluates to : `sessionId=72312312312369; Path=/; HTTPOnly`

Shouldn't the value also contain a signature value that can be verified with the application secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should. The PLAY_SESSION (or whatever you rename it to) must contain the signature part at the start, like

```
PLAY_SESSION=eyJhbGcxxxxxxxxx-userid...
```

the `eyJhbGcxxxxxxxxx` is the sign part. In the file you are linked to, you can find that this part is

Generated on line 430: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L430

And verified on line 467: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L467

Comment: Wow thank you, turns out our Cookies were not being signed because we were not using `withSession` rather we were using `withCookies` !!